# Tableau - carry out join on IP Numbers SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I am trying to put two tables into Tableau. One has IP addresses in dot format ie 192.168.32.1, and the other has IP *numbers* corresponding to cities and postcodes etc that I want to make available to visualisation.

The idea is to carry out the steps here (http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/mapping-ip-address-geocode-data)  to do a join on the two tables, where the join converts the IP address in one table into a number that can then be compared to the number in the other table.

However when i followed the steps in the guide here it ran for 40 minutes and then crashed.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

My tables are in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - I have also looked into using Computed columns to do the same thing but with no luck so far ( I am very new to SQL and cannot work out how to save then apply a function, as suggested here https://www.stev.org/post/mssqlconvertiptobigint).

Comment: Are you able to add another table in SSMS? Or do you have to stick with the two in the structure that you already have? Meaning, do you have the permissions to, say, create a table that has the data already converted for you? This would probably be more efficient than having Tableau calculate it, but would be more simple than the function.

Comment: I do have the permissions - not the knowhow unfortunately.

Comment: This is a little more complex, maybe, than can be handled entirely, but perhaps we can get you started.

Comment: what does your IP numbers table look like?

Comment: just under 4 million rows - i'm using the free version 9 from here https://lite.ip2location.com/ - it uses two columns, ipnumber start and ipnumber end. Both are 15 character varchars

Comment: Whenever something takes that long to run, the first thing I look for is an accidental Cartesian join.

Comment: IS the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I'd suggest trying to run the below query to see if it converts correctly and quickly (try to stick to under 30 seconds as a good rule of thumb) and go from there. That can tell you whether you're better off investing more time in SQL or in Tableau.

There are many approaches one could take, this is just my suggestion. What you could consider is writing a query that creates another table with the data formatted. A stored procedure that is set to run in a job (or just a job) and add to the table every few minutes (or nightly, whatever you think is appropriate) would give you the base data in SQL. Then, you could use Tableau to do the joins .

```
select [IP Address], 
--add as many columns as you want from the base table to take the place of one of the tables you join to
[CodeForIPAddressIntegerFromYourHelpSite] as 'IPINT' 
--converts IP Address to Integer - use the code from your help site
Into [IPIntegerConversion] 
--this will create a permanent table automatically
from YourTableWithIPAddress
```

This method would get you a table that has both the IP Address and the IP Integer that would allow you to link between the two (you should be able to paste the code from their site over [CodeForIPAddressIntegerFromYourHelpSite]. Then, you could set this up to run automatically in SQL Agent (which is very easy, actually). If the query itself isnt expensive, you can paste it into the job. If you pass the data already computed, it may be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will try this as soon as my attempt to see the current view fails. Currently I'm at 42 minutes, so I'm not optimistic. Quick question as I am very new to the syntax - would the code given in the MSSQL section here work?  https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/comparing-ip-addresses-in-sql

Comment: Yes, It should.

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 18
Must declare the scalar variable "@ip".
Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure BINTToIP, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 24]
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.   I'm getting this error message and am at a loss - I just naively pasted the code from my first link into the bit you specified - I don't have room here to post the full code so ill update my question

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you close:

ParseName is a function in SQL Server that parses IP addresses. I am not an expert in IP stuff and got the basics from about 5 minutes of google searching. You may have to reverse the order, but this is the basic query structure and it should be pretty fast.

```
select ip.ip
    ,parsename(ip.ip,4)*16777216 -- 2^24
    +parsename(ip.ip,3)*65536    -- 2^16
    +parsename(ip.ip,2)*256      -- 2^8
    +parsename(ip.ip,1) ip4
    ,ipv4.*
from tableWYourIPs ip
   left join ipv4 on parsename(@ip,4)*16777216 
                        +parsename(@ip,3)*65536 
                        +parsename(@ip,2)*256 
                        +parsename(@ip,1) between ipv4.start and ipv4.end
```

Make sure you apply the indexes the site recommends:

```
CREATE INDEX [ip_from] ON [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db9]([ip_from]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE INDEX [ip_to] ON [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db9]([ip_to]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The conversion follows this logic:
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-to-convert-ip-addresses-between-bigi/